# Why getting The method 'contains' isn't defined for the type 'String'. flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, contains

I am using contains method for a string in dart but getting an error like this.

What is wrong with using `.contains` for a string in dart?

This is my code:

```
String isPdf = "https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf";
isPdf.contains("pdf");
```

Error:

```
The method 'contains' isn't defined for the type 'String'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'contains'.
```

In vscode quickfix tells me that

```
change the 'contains' method to 'oscontains'.
```

Comment: Maybe you should try flutter clean and flutter pub get again

Comment: @manhtuan21 i tried it but no effect

Comment: Is that your full code? I see nothing wrong here. If possible, can you provide full code??

Comment: @YeLwinOo Thankyou bro i got the answer it's just the flutter file somehow got edited in my local directory